# Changing of limits of integral

Tags: integration

Why does $$\iiint_{E}^{}3(y^2+z^2)dV = \int_{-1}^{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}3r^2\cdot rdrd\theta dx$$ for a surface bounded by $y^2+z^2=1$, $x=-1$, and $x=2$? I understand everything except the limits $0$ and $1$. Thanks.

Comment: what is your $r$ ?

Comment: @derivative What do you mean?

Comment: $r$ is the axial distance from the $x$ axis. Since the integration domain is a piece of cylinder around that very axis, it goes from $0$ to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region of integration is a circular cylinder bounded by the circles obtained from intersecting the infinite cylinder $y^2 + z^2 = 1$ with the planes $x = -1$ and $x = 2$.  Thus, it is natural to use cylindrical coordinates with $(r, \theta)$ describing points in the $yz$-plane and the natural coordinate $x$.

Each slice of the solid with a plane $x = c$ for a constant $-1 \leq c \leq 2$ yields a circular disk of radius $1$ centered at the origin $(y,z) = (0,0)$ of the plane.  In that region, the coordinates $(r,\theta)$ range over $0 \leq r \leq 1$ and $0 \leq \theta < 2 \pi$.

Answer (score 1):

So, the cylinder $y^2+z^2=1$ has the circle of radius $1$ as its base; $r$ is the parameter in cylindrical coordinate system. In your situation $r$ changes from $0$ to $1$ as we integrate (over the volume of the cylinder).